# I get TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple) when trying to draw circle in cropped window

Tags: python, opencv

I looked through the other posts and nothings seems to fix my problem. As of now I can use my`mouse_draw_rect` function to draw a rectangle on my video stream and create a cropped window. I want to then further draw shapes in this cropped window, but when I try to call my `select_point` function my program crashes and I get the following: `TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)`. The Error happens on the `cv2.circle(cropped_window,point,(0,0,255),2)` line of code.

Here is my following code, which can be run using opencv:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
_, first_frame = cap.read()


def mouse_draw_rect(event, x, y, flags, params):
    global point1, point2, drawing, first_frame
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        if drawing is False:
            drawing = True
            point1 = ()
            point2 = ()
            point1 = (x, y)
            print(point1)
            print(point2)
        else:
            drawing = False

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        if drawing is True:
            point2 = (x, y)
            drawing = False

def select_point(event, x, y, flags, params):
    global point, point_selected
    if event == cv2.EVENT_MBUTTONDOWN:
        point = (x, y)
        point_selected = True
        print(point)

drawing = False
point_selected = False

point1 = ()
point2 = ()
point = ()

cv2.namedWindow('Original')

cv2.setMouseCallback("Original", mouse_draw_rect)

while True:

    ret, frame = cap.read( )

    if point1 and point2:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, point1, point2, (0, 0, 0), 2)
        first_frame_roi = first_frame[point1[1]:point2[1], point1[0]:point2[0]]
        cropped_window = frame[point1[1]:point2[1], point1[0]:point2[0], :]

        cv2.imshow('Cropped Window', cropped_window)

        cv2.namedWindow('Cropped Window')
        cv2.setMouseCallback("Cropped Window", select_point)
        if point_selected is True:
            cv2.circle(cropped_window,point,(0,0,255),2)

    cv2.imshow('Original', frame)


    key = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if key == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Let me know if you require further details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation:

> cv2.circle(img, center, radius, color[, thickness[, lineType[, shift]]]) → img

The 3rd argument is the radius which is expected to be a number (an integer in this case) and not a tuple. I think you used the arguments in the wrong order in your call.

Comment: You are right I completely overlooked the radius argument, probably a sign I should take a break. Thanks!